# When to unhook events in Xamarin Custom Renderers

Tags: c#, xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.forms, event-handling

It is well known that when hooking up event handling in code we run the risk of leaving the objects in memory and thus creating a memory leak.

In order to achieve some special functionality (disabling cut and copy) I need to implement custom renderers on UWP. While the disabling of cut and copy are not strictly relevant to the question I had to hook up event handlers in order to achieve this.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (this.Control == null) { return; }

    this.Control.CopyingToClipboard += Control_CopyingToClipboard;
    this.Control.CuttingToClipboard += Control_CuttingToClipboard;
}

private void Control_CuttingToClipboard(TextBox sender, 
                                        TextControlCuttingToClipboardEventArgs args)
{
    args.Handled = true;
}

private void Control_CopyingToClipboard(TextBox sender, 
                                        TextControlCopyingToClipboardEventArgs args)
{
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

**Question**

What is the correct place to unhook these event handlers to prevent any form of leakage?

I have noticed that there is an `IDisposable` implementation not the `VisualElementRenderer<TElement, TNativeElement>` in the `UWP` platform namespace however I haven't been able to reliably prove that this gets called.

**Update**

As per *Michał Żołnieruk*s suggestion I have added unhooking inside a check for the `OldElement` not being null however I never see any proof that this gets called.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (this.Control == null) { return; }

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        System.Debug.WriteLine("I NEVER SEE THIS");

        this.Control.CopyingToClipboard -= Control_CopyingToClipboard;
        this.Control.CuttingToClipboard -= Control_CuttingToClipboard;
    }

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        this.Control.CopyingToClipboard += Control_CopyingToClipboard;
        this.Control.CuttingToClipboard += Control_CuttingToClipboard;
    }
}
```

When the controls are removed from the UI should these renderers be cleaned up and thus fire the `OnElementChanged` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the article about Custom Renderers here: [Implementing a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view)
It contains a template for a custom renderer's OnElementChanged method:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<NativeListView> e)
{
  base.OnElementChanged (e);

  if (Control == null) {
    // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with
    // the SetNativeControl method
  }

  if (e.OldElement != null) {
    // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
  }

  if (e.NewElement != null) {
    // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
  }
}
```

So you should unhook your events when OldElement is not null, and hook them when NewElement is present.

As for the follow up question in the comments (should we unsubscribe if the second if above was not triggered): my understanding is that the lifetimes of both of these objects (so renderer and native control) are the same and in such case there's no need to unsubscribe events manually. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not entirely sure why I didn't include the details in my question but when I have implemented the e.OldElement check in my renderer and stick a breakpoint in there I have never been able to have that breakpoint hit. This makes me think I could potentially be looking at a memory leak.

Comment: you're welcome, I added an additional comment about it.